# Django Token based authentication using PyJWT , issue with verification of token

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am implementing Token Based authentication in Python Django and therefore I am following the Token based authentication steps, as described here:

> In token-based authentication, cookies and sessions will not be used.
>   A token will be used for authenticating a user for each request to the
>   server. Let's redesign the first scenario with token-based
>   authentication.
>
> It will use the following flow of control:
>
> 1. The user provides a username and password in the login form and clicksLog In.
> 2. After a request is made, validate the user on the backend by querying in the database. If the request is valid, create a token by
>      using the user information fetched from the database, and then return
>      that information in the response header so that we can store the token
>      browser in local storage.
> 3. Provide token information in every request header for accessing restricted endpoints in the application.
> 4. If the token fetched from the request header information is valid, let the user access the specified end point, and respond with JSON or
>      XML.

I am done with the first 2 steps listed above. I need to proceed with step 3 and step 4. Therefore, I am writing a Django decorator that would do the task for us.

However, after the authentication step I am a little bit stuck.

Here is the AngularJS code that would send `teacher_id` and `token` to the server:

```
get_teacher_profile : function(teacher_id,token) {

    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token;

    return $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_manager/teacher/" + teacher_id + '/' + token)
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                        return response.data;
                    } else { return "Error"; }
                }, function(error) {
                    return null;
                });
},
```

As per the Django rest framework here is the router specified at the urls.py:

```
router.register(r'teacher', view.TeacherViewSet)
```

...and here is the `TeacherViewSet` class:

```
class TeacherViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Teacher.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Teacher_Serializer
```

Now I need to verify the token in `TeacherViewSet`. I have tried some decorators but I've not been able to access the token I set in the header in the `TeacherViewSet`. I am using PyJWT for Token based authentication. If anyone has encountered this before please let me know.

Comment: Hey. Is there a reason you don't wanna use the DRF Token Authentication? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out:

http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#rest-framework-jwt-auth

This will take care of JWT support for you when dealing with django-rest-framework.